# Google map multiple markers infowindow open from external link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

Created a Google markers map and also listed locations name next to map - Its working fine

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6eYQP/1/)

**Target-**
How can I open corresponding  **infowindow** when I click on listed each location's name ?

Code

```
var markers = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];

function initializeMaps() {
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(pos);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

}
initializeMaps()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop where you create the markers also create the links and attach a click-listener that triggers the marker-click:

```
(function(marker){
            google.maps.event
              .addDomListener($('<li/>')
                              .text(markers[i][0])
                               .appendTo('#list')[0],
                              'click',
                               function(){
                                google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click',{});
                               });
 })(marker);
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/HNd6H/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/HNd6H/)

Comment: I expecting this , but can we do this without 'li' append [  I need to keep 'li' in html ] - Very thanks for your help

Comment: You may store a property(e.g. ID or index) that enables you to access the correct link in the markers-array. When the indexes are equal(currently they are) you may use the `i` directly inside the loop: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/HNd6H/2/

Comment: Yes thanks , Please edit ur first  answer , I gave you up vote