# Google Maps link to marker from outside map

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I'm trying to make a list of links, correlate to the correct marker on a google map. I have multiple markers and this is what I have:

You can see a live example of my code by viewing source on this page:

```
http://79.170.40.181/cranes.co.uk/stockists/
```

I'm using Wordpress's Advanced Custom Fields plugin to generate the map and its markers. I'm using their example code given on their [docs pages](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/) but I'm trying to add additional functionality. I just need some advice on where I put this piece of code to enable my list of links to relate to each marker on the map:

```
var name = $('#listdata').find('.clickaway');

google.maps.event.addDomListener(name, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    alert('found me');
});
```

My list of links has a structure of:

```
<ul id="listdata"
   <li><a href="#" class="clickaway">Location 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="clickaway">Location 2</a></li>
   ...
</ul>
```

For reference I have pasted my full Google Maps code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
/* Google Maps */
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom        : 16,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
          mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
        }
    };

    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];

    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){

        add_marker( $(this), map );

    });

    // center map
    center_map( map );

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
    var image = 'http://79.170.40.181/cranes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/pin.png';

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map,
        icon        : image
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html(),
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });

    }

}



/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 )
    {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 16 );
    }
    else
    {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }

}

// Call it
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        render_map( $(this) );

    });

});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here's how I loop through and display the markers:

```
 <?php if( have_rows('locations') ): ?>
            <div class="acf-map">
            <?php while ( have_rows('locations') ) : the_row(); 

                $location = get_sub_field('stockist_location'); ?>

                <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo   $location['lng']; ?>">
                                <h4 class="title">Title</h4>
                                        <p class="address">Address</p>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Can anyone advise or give me some help how I might get this working?

Comment: add an Id to each marker, then when you click on the list, the list item has this Id, you find the marker with that Id and open the InfoWindow

Comment: Thanks @FelipeP. How does that relate to my code though? I can generate unique ID's for each of my links but how do I target them with jQuery?

Comment: where you define the map you could add a function that receives this Id and open the InfoWindow, and on the links have click="openInfo(theIdWeAreTalking)", don't know if that will be available on scope, but maybe you should give it a try and see if it works

Comment: No this doesn't work

Comment: what do you actually want to do? Is it click on the link on the left and focus on the map or link to the website of the business?

Comment: @David, The former. I'd like to click on the link and focus the map and open the info window. If you have any advice I'd love to hear it, I'm completely stuck!

Comment: i would answer this but its being answered on the link below, At the moment you are seperating your markers from your list of businesses, combine these and add an event handler to open the relevant window...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751623/google-map-multiple-markers-infowindow-open-from-external-link

Comment: @David, Thanks so if I use the code in the accepted answer where do I put it in my code? I've tried adding it at the bottom but no LI's get added to my target DIV. Help?! My edited code: http://pastebin.com/0mbBQbkn

Comment: did you change the marker function to `.appendTo('#listdata')[0]`? actually you also need to create the markers array...ill give a stab now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js fiddle using your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dheffernan/3xkuybrf/

A couple of points to note:

1. leave the div listdata empty
2. The inserted divs for the links, you may need to modify this (see code below i left a comment beside the jquery that appends your links into the listdata div  - i added a css class just for jsfiddle to style it but you can remove this...
3. Replace the js with below.

   ```
       /* Google Maps */

   (function($) {

       function render_map( $el ) {

           // var
           var $markers = $(document).find('.marker');


           // vars
           var args = {
               zoom        : 16,
               center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
               mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
               scrollwheel: false,
               mapTypeControlOptions: {
                 mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
               }
           };

           // create map               
           var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

           // add a markers reference
           map.markers = [];
           // add markers
           index=0;
           $markers.each(function(){
               add_marker( $(this), map, index);
               index++;
           });

           // center map
           center_map( map );

           }

       function add_marker( $marker, map, index ) {

           // var
           var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );
           var image = 'http://79.170.40.181/cranes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/pin.png';

           // create marker
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position    : latlng,
               map         : map,
               icon        : image
           });

           // add to array
           map.markers.push( marker );


           // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
           if( $marker.html() )
           {
               $('#listdata').append('<div class= "linkage" id="p'+index+'">'+$marker.html()+'</div>'); // change html here if you want but eave id intact!!

               $(document).on('click', '#p'+index, function(){
                   infowindow.open(map, marker);
                   setTimeout(function () { infowindow.close(); }, 5000);
               });

               // create info window
               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                   content     : $marker.html(),
               });




               // show info window when marker is clicked
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                   infowindow.open( map, marker );

               });

           }

           }


       function center_map( map ) {

           // vars
           var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

           // loop through all markers and create bounds
           $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

               var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

               bounds.extend( latlng );

           });

           // only 1 marker?
           if( map.markers.length == 1 )
           {
               // set center of map
               alert(bounds);
               map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
               map.setZoom( 16 );
           }
           else
           {
               // fit to bounds
               map.fitBounds( bounds );
           }

           }

       // Call it


         $(document).ready(function(){

           $('.acf-map').each(function(){

               render_map( $(this) );

           });

       });



   })(jQuery);
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I get a console error x 2: Markers is undefined and another error that reads unexpected token =. Do I post your code above in my UL#listdata? I think I'm a tad lost if I'm honest.

Comment: ill have a look later...basically have a look at the jsfiddle on the accepted answer, you need to create a js array of markers using php so its dynamic and then recreate your list on the left using the array.

Comment: updated there. It should work with what you have already, just dont put links into listdata, it will do this for you!

Comment: David you have saved my bacon! Thanks for taking a detailed look and giving such a detailed answer!